# Unhandled rejection TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js

Model.query("SELECT id, name, description, user_type, CAST(COLUMN_JSON(permissions) as char) as permissions, deleted, created_at, updated_at FROM roles WHERE id = " + req.params.id.replace(/(['\"])/g, '\$1')  + " AND deleted = false", { type: Model.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT},{ type: Model.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}, function(err, data){}
//// I am getting error at this line what is the problem????

Answer (score 0):

Your sending  two time the same object  { type: Model.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT} in your raw query which might be the error.

you can also check the number of parameters should be passed in a raw query 
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/raw-queries/

Hope this will help you .